# Aggregate sequential time recordings in R

Tags: r, data.table, time-series, aggregate

I am trying to calculate the sequential recordings in a time series, and aggregate the data for these sequences.

**Example Data**

Here is an example of the data taken at a maximum frequency of 1 second:

```
timestamp   Value
06:07:23    0.439
06:07:24    0.556
06:07:25    0.430
06:07:26    0.418
06:07:27    0.407
06:07:47    0.439
06:07:48    0.420
06:07:49    0.405
09:55:21    0.507
09:55:22    0.439
10:03:24    0.439
10:03:25    0.439
10:03:36    1.708
10:03:37    0.608
10:03:38    0.439
10:03:46    0.484
10:03:47    0.380
10:03:48    0.607
10:03:49    0.439
10:03:50    0.439
10:03:51    0.439
10:03:52    0.430
10:03:53    0.439
10:03:54    4.924
10:03:55    1.012
10:03:56    0.887
10:03:57    0.439
10:03:58    0.439
10:04:18    0.447
10:04:19    0.447
```

As can be seen, there are periods whereby a value is taken every second. I am trying to find a way to aggregate if there was no gap between the observations to end up with something as follows:

```
timestamp   max     duration
06:07:23    0.556   5
06:07:47    0.439   3
09:55:21    0.507   2
10:03:24    0.439   2
10:03:36    1.708   3
10:03:46    1.012   13
10:04:18    0.447   2
```

I am struggling to find a way of grouping the data by the sequential data. The closest answer I have been able to find is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341123/identify-time-sequence-in-data-and-subset-by-that-sequence-r), however, the answers were provided over three and a half years ago and I was struggling to get the `data.table` method working.

Any ideas much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an attempt in `data.table`:

```
dat[, 
  .(timestamp = timestamp[1], max = max(Value), duration=.N),
  by = cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(as.POSIXct(dat$timestamp, format="%H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")) > 1))
]

#   cumsum timestamp   max duration
#1:      0  06:07:23 0.556        5
#2:      1  06:07:47 0.439        3
#3:      2  09:55:21 0.507        2
#4:      3  10:03:24 0.439        2
#5:      4  10:03:36 1.708        3
#6:      5  10:03:46 4.924       13
#7:      6  10:04:18 0.447        2
```

Comment: I was trying something almost the same. We can also use `as.ITime(timestamp)` in `data.table`.